# Best way to get rows changed in an sqlite db

Tags: sqlite

I'm watching an sqlite db which an app uses.

I want to know what changes have been made since
I last checked.

I can dump to sql and diff against the last dump,
but it seems there should be a better way.

Is there?

Thanks,
Kent

PS Not to be coy, specifics: I'm managing photos with Shotwell, which has a great GUI.
I'm mirroring Shotwell's db in Postgresql, where I've restructured and augmented to my liking. After a Shotwell session, which involves adding, tagging, adjusting ... I want
to apply those changes to Postgres.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/422951/keeping-a-log-table-in-sqlite-database

Answer (score 1):

Add a field `named _changed` to your table(s). On every manipulation (`update`, `insert into`...) of a row set the field to the current timestamp. Now you can check which rows have been updated since.

Comment: The db I'm interested in belongs to an app, I can't modify it to add the functionality I'm interested in.